# cakephp app::import recaptcha library

Tags: cakephp, recaptcha

I'm trying to include recaptcha in my cakePHP application.  I am trying to use App::import('vendor', 'Recaptcha.recaptchalib');
It appears that it loads fine, but I get an error: call to undefined function when calling a function inside of recaptchalib.php.  App::import says the class must be instantiated, but there are no classes inside of the library, only functions.  How can I make this work?

Comment: have you tried recaptcha plugin from CakeDC yet ? https://github.com/CakeDC/recaptcha

Comment: Yes, I had problems with that as well.  If you have had success and would be willing to help a bit, I'd give it another shot.

Comment: In what folder did you place the library?